# How can I bind a text block to the sum of a DataGrid column in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have a class Player that has fields "position" and "salary". I have another class PlayerList that extends observable collection and contains a list of players. I have bound a data grid to a player list. How can I bind a Text block to the sum of the Salary column? I would also like to bind a a text block to the number of players with position listed as "Forward". Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create properties in your viewmodel and bind to them. You can have a property SalarySum on the PlayerList class and another property of that class might be a collection of Players that are forwards. You can then bind to that properties like you did before with the players.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem in your case is the thinking of how you to solve the problem in the MVVM way
because the `View` doesn't take any logic this is part of your `ViewModel` so it should just a normal binding to your 
`ViewModel` like [nvoigt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15516632/1993545) told you.

**conclusion**
a `ViewModel` shape all Data to fit in your `View`